# Saving user input in tic tac toe board

Tags: c++

I have written a C++ tic tac toe game.  It works however I think it would be nicer if I showed the user how the board looks after every turn.  I got the board to show up, however it shows the default board. I tried putting in code to show the board with the x or o but i just get a error saying squareChoice is not declared in this scope. I am also getting an error for my two if states after the while (stating expected unqualiftied-id before if) . Please help, I would greatly appreciate it. Here is my code:

```
/*
Sophia Ali
   Template for TicTacToe.cpp (CS-509 Assignment 5)
can't get program to store x and o in the board
*/


#include<iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;

/*
   Game status enumeration
*/
enum Status { WIN, DRAW, CONTINUE, QUIT };


/*
   Function prototypes
*/
// showBoard: Show current state of board
void showBoard( const char board[], int boardSize );
// checkGameState: Returns WIN or CONTINUE
Status checkGameState( const char board[] );
int getHumanSquare( const char board[] );
int getComputerSquare( const char board[] );
// checkBadSquare: Checks to see if a chosen square is already taken; returns
//                 true if already taken; used by getHumanSquare and
//                 getComputerSquare functions above.
bool checkBadSquare( const char board[], int squareNum );
int getrandint( int min, int max );




int main()
{
    char board[] = "123456789";   // 10 element char board
    const int boardSize = 10;
    Status gameState = CONTINUE;
    int gametype, squareChoice, turnNum = 0;
    char currentSymbol;           // 'o' or 'x'



    cout << "\n This is a Tic Tac Toe program. Choose the type of game: "
         << "\n (1) human o vs. human x    (2) human o vs. dumb computer x"
         << "\n\n -> ";
    cin  >> gametype;


    /* Show the current state of Tic Tac Toe board. */
    cout << gameState;
    cout << "\n\n";




    /*
       Main game loop
    */
    while ( gameState == 2 )
    {
        /* Increment turnNum by 1. */
        turnNum++;


        /* If turnNum equal to 10
              Set gameState to DRAW.
              Break out of while loop. */
        if ( turnNum == 10 )
        {
            gameState = DRAW;
            break;
        }
        /* If we are on an odd-numbered turn
              Print "It's o's turn."
              Set currentSymbol to 'o'.
              Call getHumanSquare function to get squareChoice.*/
        if ( turnNum%2 != 0)
        {
            cout << "It's o's turn.";
            currentSymbol = 'o';
            cout << "\n\n";

            getHumanSquare(board);
            showBoard( board, boardSize );
        }

        /* Else (we are on an even-numbered turn)
            Print "It's x's turn."
            Set currentSymbol to 'x'. */
        else
        {
            cout << "It's x's turn.";
            currentSymbol = 'x';
            cout << "\n\n";
            showBoard( board, boardSize );

        }


        /*   If the gametype is 1 (human vs. human)
              Call getHumanSquare function to get squareChoice.*/
        if ( gametype == 1 )
        {
            getHumanSquare(board);


        }


        /* Else (gametype is 2 (human vs. computer))
           Call getComputerSquare function to get squareChoice. */
        else

            getComputerSquare(board);



        /* If squareChoice is -1 (human player quit)
              Set gameState to QUIT.*/
        if ( squareChoice == -1 )
        {
            gameState = QUIT;
        }

        /* Else
           Insert currentSymbol into board at (squareChoice - 1).
           Show the current state of the Tic Tac Toe board.
           Call checkGameState function to determine the gameState. */
        else
        {
            if (squareChoice == 1 && board[1] == '1')
            board[1] = currentSymbol;
            else if (squareChoice == 2 && board[2] == '2')
            board[2] = currentSymbol;
            else if (squareChoice == 3 && board[3] == '3')
            board[3] = currentSymbol;
            else if (squareChoice == 4 && board[4] == '4')
            board[4] = currentSymbol;
            else if (squarechoice == 5 && board[5] == '5')
            board[5] = currentSymbol;
            else if (squarechoice == 6 && board[6] == '6')
            board[6] = currentSymbol;
            else if (squarechoice == 7 && board[7] == '7')
            board[7] = currentSymbol;
            else if (squarechoice == 8 && board[8] == '8')
            board[8] = currentSymbol;
            else if (squarechoice == 9 && board[9] == '9')
            board[9] = currentSymbol;
            else
            {
                cout <<"Invalid move";
                turnNum--;
            }
        }

            checkGameState(board);

        }

}// end while


    /* If gameState is WIN
          print "Player " currentSymbol " is the winner." */
    if ( gameState == WIN)
        cout << "Player " << currentSymbol << " is the winner.";

    /* If gameState is DRAW
          print "It's a draw." */
    if ( gameState == DRAW )
        cout << "It's a draw.";

    return 0;
}

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

void showBoard( const char board [], int size )
{
    cout << endl;

    for ( int i = 0; i < size ; i++ )
    {
        cout << board[ i ] << " ";
        if ( ( i + 1 ) % 3 == 0 )
            cout << endl;
    }

    cout << endl;
}

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

Status checkGameState( const char board[] )
{
    // Board       Array
    //
    // 1 2 3       0 1 2
    // 4 5 6  -->  3 4 5
    // 7 8 9       6 7 8
    //
    // Diagonal winners
    if ( board[ 0 ] == board[ 4 ] && board[ 0 ] == board[ 8 ] )
        return WIN;
    else if ( board[ 2 ] == board[ 4 ] && board[ 4 ] == board[ 6 ] )
        return WIN;
    // Horizontal winners
    else if ( board[ 0 ] == board[ 1 ] && board[ 1 ] == board[ 2 ] )
        return WIN;
    else if ( board[ 3 ] == board[ 4 ] && board[ 4 ] == board[ 5 ] )
        return WIN;
    else if ( board[ 6 ] == board[ 7 ] && board[ 7 ] == board[ 8 ] )
        return WIN;
    // Vertical winners
    else if ( board[ 0 ] == board[ 3 ] && board[ 3 ] == board[ 6 ] )
        return WIN;
    else if ( board[ 1 ] == board[ 4 ] && board[ 4 ] == board[ 7 ] )
        return WIN;
    else if ( board[ 2 ] == board[ 5 ] && board[ 5 ] == board[ 8 ] )
        return WIN;
    else
        // No one has won yet
        return CONTINUE;
}

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

int getHumanSquare( const char board[] )
{
    int squareNum;

    cout << "\n Input the number of an empty square: (-1 to quit) ";
    cin  >> squareNum;

    while ( checkBadSquare( board, squareNum ) == true )
    {
        cout << "\n Bad input. Choose another square: ";
        cin >> squareNum;
    }

    return squareNum;
}

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

int getComputerSquare( const char board[] )
{
    int squareNum;

    squareNum = getrandint( 1, 9 );

    while ( checkBadSquare( board, squareNum ) == true )
    {
        squareNum = getrandint( 1, 9 );
    }

    return squareNum;
}

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

bool checkBadSquare( const char board[], int squareNum )
{
    int realSquareNum = squareNum - 1; // count from 0

    if ( squareNum == -1 )
        return false;  // Let quit code pass as a valid square
    else if ( squareNum > 9 )
        return true;   // Square numbers out of range are invalid
    else if ( board[ realSquareNum ] == 'o' || board[ realSquareNum ] == 'x' )
        return true;   // Already taken squares are invalid
    else
        return false;  // Valid square number
}

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

int getrandint( int min, int max )
{

    int scale, shift;
    scale = max - min + 1;
    shift = min;
    return rand() % scale + shift;
}
```

Comment: Where is the error within the code you posted?

Comment: Just a tip, don't use that often "else if". "switch()" would be much more readable.

Comment: @ValekHalfHeart the error is in these lines: 
        print "Player " currentSymbol " is the winner." */
    if ( gameState == WIN)
        cout << "Player " << currentSymbol << " is the winner.";

    /* If gameState is DRAW
          print "It's a draw." */
    if ( gameState == DRAW )
        cout << "It's a draw.";

the error states "expected unqualified-id before 'if'"

Answer (score 1):

Spelling of squareChoice  is wrong in most of the `if statement`:
It should be **squareChoice** not **squarechoice**

So replace:

```
else
        {
            if (squareChoice == 1 && board[1] == '1')
            board[1] = currentSymbol;
            else if (squareChoice == 2 && board[2] == '2')
            board[2] = currentSymbol;
            else if (squareChoice == 3 && board[3] == '3')
            board[3] = currentSymbol;
            else if (squareChoice == 4 && board[4] == '4')
            board[4] = currentSymbol;
            else if (squarechoice == 5 && board[5] == '5')
            board[5] = currentSymbol;
            else if (squarechoice == 6 && board[6] == '6')
            board[6] = currentSymbol;
            else if (squarechoice == 7 && board[7] == '7')
            board[7] = currentSymbol;
            else if (squarechoice == 8 && board[8] == '8')
            board[8] = currentSymbol;
            else if (squarechoice == 9 && board[9] == '9')
            board[9] = currentSymbol;
            else
            {
                cout <<"Invalid move";
                turnNum--;
            }
        }
```

by

```
 else
        {
            if (squareChoice == 1 && board[1] == '1')
                board[1] = currentSymbol;
            else if (squareChoice == 2 && board[2] == '2')
                board[2] = currentSymbol;
            else if (squareChoice == 3 && board[3] == '3')
                board[3] = currentSymbol;
            else if (squareChoice == 4 && board[4] == '4')
                board[4] = currentSymbol;
            else if (squareChoice == 5 && board[5] == '5')/*SPELLING MISTAKE*/
                board[5] = currentSymbol;
            else if (squareChoice == 6 && board[6] == '6')
                board[6] = currentSymbol;
            else if (squareChoice == 7 && board[7] == '7')
                board[7] = currentSymbol;
            else if (squareChoice == 8 && board[8] == '8')
                board[8] = currentSymbol;
            else if (squareChoice == 9 && board[9] == '9')
                board[9] = currentSymbol;
            else
            {
                cout <<"Invalid move";
                turnNum--;
            }
        }
```

An extra closing brace "`}`" is in main function.Remove following line to fix it.

```
}// end while.  THIS IS NOT NEEDED.REMOVE THIS LINE FROM YOUR CODE.
```

I have fixed the compilation error(s).**[DEMO](http://ideone.com/VMAH9C)**. There are still some logical and runtime errors.

**UPD**: As per @Ben Voigt Comment, the runtime error could be due to board[9], out of range.
After reading your following comment: `// 10 element char board` , I think

```
char board[] = "123456789";
```

should be replaced by:

```
 char board[] = "0123456789";
```

*Even after fixing it, still there are some logical and run-time errors.*

Answer (score 0):

The big long if has already been pointed out as having problems.  You can replace it with a much shorter test:

```
if (squareChoice >= 1 && squareChoice <= 9 && board[squareChoice-1] == '0' + squareChoice) {
    board[squareChoice-1] = currentSymbol;
}
else {
    cout <<"Invalid move";
    turnNum--;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the shorter code! would you happen to know what the error "expected unqualifed id before 'if'" error means?

Comment: @user2085224: I think ritesh figured that one out -- you have an extra closing brace.